Browser "disable cache" Header no CORS effect
I have a web app that doesn't allow the Cache-Control header in CORS requests.
If I explicitly set said header, the request gets denied appropriately...
Now I open my browser dev tools, activate "disable cache" and execute the following command
fetch("https://my.domain/ressource")

I can see in the network tab of my browser dev tools, that the request has been sent.
I can see, that the request has the Cache-Control header set to 'no-cache'.
I can also see, that the request was not denied by CORS errors but answered with a 200 status code.
Why and how?
Do browsers only show the Cache-Control header but not actually include it in the request?
Side note:
It doesn't seem to matter, if I do the experiment in Chrome or Firefox. Both browers behave the same...
edit:
I tested the request header using this online tool.
They are infect send with the request...
So new theory: since CORS is handled by the browsers, are they smart enough to realize that they injected the problematic header and therfor ignore the cors issues?

You say the header wasn't sent, but that the browser shows that it was sent. If the browser says it sent the headers, then it sent the headers. Can you dump the headers on your server to see what it received? Can you compare any other headers to see why the server behaves differently?
